# Calculating an Average Duration in Google Sheets With Parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've been trying to get a Google Sheets formula working for this scenario for a while now to the point I can feel Google laughing at me.

[Here's the current table I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf4mt.png)

Here are the ranges I'm working with

A Column - Time and date of first request

B Column - Time and date of first response

F Column - Type (In this example, the type is marked as "LMM Reminder"

How I calculated the total task in Column W is;

`=COUNTIFS(F:F, "LMM Request", A:A, ">="&W14, A:A, "<="&X14)`

Which uses a date range with the cells W14 and X14.

My question is, can anyone think of a way to calculate the average response time, taking into account that they need to be marked in Column F as "LMM Request", have column A be between the date ranges entered in W14 and X14, and then subtract the First Response Time (Column B) from the First Request time (Column A) to produce a duration, and then obtain the average of all obtained durations.

Comment: You want the count of dates with "LMM Request" and outside or inside of the date range?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
=COUNTIFS(F:F, "LMM Request", A:A, "<="&W14, A:A, ">="&X14)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the dates/times in columns A & B are in a standard MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format. There may be some necessary adjustments depending on the date format you are using if it is different.

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER({B:B-A:A},F:F="LMM Request",A:A>=W14,A:A<=X14))
```

Comment: Hey LASheets,

It looks like your formula is the closest to what I'm looking for, however it still produces an error with the FILTER function, claiming > No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

To clarify, yes, columns A and B are in MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS format.

Other than that, I think you understand what I'm asking and thank you so much for trying, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If FILTER says there aren't any rows meeting the conditions (and you're sure there are examples that should be), then I would guess there's something wrong with either the references, the logic, or the column formatting. The one inconsistency I can see is in your original post you had both "LMM Request" and "LMM Reminder" as the string value for column F. But it's tough to say without seeing the actual sheet or a screenshot. Even if you can just give a couple of rows in a screenshot, that would be helpful to see. I'm happy to keep looking into it though!